# Unable to login - need to boot into single user and recover password?

Tags: boot, xubuntu, login, password

A week ago I installed Xubuntu (20.04?) on a Dell Latitude e6530 that had Windows 10 "ready to install" (I never agreed to MS terms, so didn't activate). I was the only user and had root access and (I'm assuming) superuser rights.

After installing Wine and Scribus and learning some how to navigate the system, I changed my password, set to No Password on Login, and noticing I wasn't an administrator, made myself one. I then closed lid (thinking that would put changes into effect - doh!), and once I opened lid, was prompted for a password, which was not accepted - neither the new one (which I uncharacteristically had written down) nor the old.

With help from Ask Ubuntu folks, I made it to the Grub (2.04) prompt to get into recovery mode. There I got stumped. Didn't know which to choose: Linux 5.4.0-96-generic or Linux 5.4.0-42-generic. The -96- appears to be more recent than my Xubuntu (if it indeed is 20.04 from April 2020). So I'm guessing I should edit the -42- one. [Dunno if using the wrong one will screw things up (even more).]

Once I get to the right recovery mode, and am presumably able to boot into single user mode, how do I recover my password, if that's what I need to do? And should I un-administrator myself?

Or perhaps I should cut my losses and reinstall the whole salami. After all, I don't understand most commands others have kindly offered; I don't think blindly following (anything or anyone) is a good idea.

Thank you one and all for your gracious support, including the (staffer?) who sent me a Yes/No query whether any of 16 suggestions had helped/resolved my issue. All I could answer is "not yet", but that wasn't an option, so I've been silent to that query so far.

Comment: This would be easier if you were precise on release details; but the 5.4 kernel you mention IS the GA kernel for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Ubuntu LTS releases have two kernel stack choices; GA being one). The 5.4.0-42-generic kernel was likely what was on your installation media (it matches https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/20.04.2/ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.manifest), where as the 5.4.0-96 is with security patches applied likely obtained during upgrades during or post-installation.  You can use either for fixing issues; -96 will be safer.

Comment: Thank you guiverc, that's helpful for my level of understanding. I'd be happy to be precise on release details if I knew them or how to find them. I only know that the USB drive I installed from only contains an efi directory with 3 files: bootx64.efi, grubx64.efi and mmx64.efi from 7/29/2020. I don't know whether that's the date the files were copied to the thumbdrive or a release date. That's why I speculated that I have Xubuntu 20.04. Do you think that's a safe assumption?

Comment: I thought I had effected a recovery after successfully changing the password at root@hulda-Latitude-E6530:~# But system didn't reboot on entering exec /sbin/init. Turning the laptop off didn't bring me a restored system, either. So I decided to cut my losses and reinstall.